# Spring Scheduled - Wakeup process

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000) triggers the method all five second. This is working perfect. Is there a way to wakup the Thread to call is directly and avoid waiting to fulfill the next five minutes?

Comment: Do you want to run the method manually at times? If yes, simplest solution would be to expose it as API as well and just trigger whenever is required. Other solutions will require exposing custom beans. Check this out - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks

Comment: No, because than it can happen that both are running in paralell. I want to avoid waiting the five seconds so the Spring scheduler should skip waiting an call it directly.

Comment: Then there is no automated way. Check the article (section 10.) I posted earlier. There is a way to remember the last execution time and then use it to re-trigger. However, it has to be done programmatically.